# Adding Esri Vector Basemaps to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am wanting to add the ESRI Vector Basemaps http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?id=30de8da907d240a0bccd5ad3ff25ef4a#overview to QGIS 3.4.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Vector-Tiles-Reader-QGIS-Plugin https://github.com/geometalab/Vector-Tiles-Reader-QGIS-Plugin/wiki/Help but Esri don't conform to the /{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf format

Comment: ESRI just has the X and Y reverse placeholder order It is .PBF MapBox Vector Tile Format and they provide a TileJSON response and use GL JSON Stylesheets   Z/Y/X  same for the raster tiles from ESRI.  https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf        defaultStyles: "/resources/styles",
tiles: [
"/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf"
],rows: 512,
cols: 512,

Comment: The field vector_layers is required but not found this is an invalid TileJSON is the error message that the plugin gives.  https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson-spec/issues/14   one issue also is that ESRI uses Index (not flat) vector tiles so there is some intelligence needed in the mapping clients to know to overzoom some tiles